# how to remove First text from string in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

```
var selectedCustomers = document.getElementById("hfCustomerID");
```

> output :- "|1|2|3"
>
> this is my hidden field in which pushed value stored.
>
> values in hidden field are stored "|1|2|3" like this
>
> because of this when string is split and pushed in array at index 0 =
>   "" is stored.
>
> how to check and remove First "|" from string in jquery before pushing it to array?

Comment: use slice like `var data = "|1|2|3";


console.log(data.slice(1))`

Comment: Try with var result = selectedCustomers.substring(1, selectedCustomers.length) or selectedCostumers.substr(1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"|1|2|3".slice(1).split('|');
```

use slice() to remove the first character.

```
"|1|2|3".match(/[^|]/g);
```

or use Regx

Answer (score 1):

You can use substr to remove the first char like this,

```
string.substr(1);
```

```js
console.log("|1|2|3".substr(1).split('|'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in multiple ways.

If value is always expected like you mentioned then can use `string.substr(1).split('|')` as suggested in one of the answer, else you can do it using "filter".

```
selectedCustomers.split('|').filter(function(value) {
return value !== "" && value !== null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring` to remove first character from string.

```js
var trimmed = "|1|2|3".substring(1);
alert (trimmed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the code below:

```
var selectedCustomers = document.getElementById("hfCustomerID").substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("|1|2|3".slice(1).split('|'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following way you can do this.

```
trimmed= "|1|2|3".substring(1).split('|');
alert(trimmed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do same thing using jQuery but I have to remove digits from the sentence if the first word was made of digits. So I wrote following code to satisfy my requirement:

```
var itsValue = $('#fieldname').val();
var sentence = (itsValue.match(/^[0-9]/g))?removeFirstDigits(itsValue):itsValue;

function removeFirstDigits(itsValue) {
    var senitizedval = itsValue.split(' ').slice(1);
    return senitizedval.join(' ');
}
```

Hope you found it helpful.